# CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException android

Tags: android

In my code, when cursor is null i encounter the exception of `CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException Index 0 requested, with a size of 0 in Android`

How can I fix this problem??

```
public Cursor getCustAccount(long custRef){
    openReadable();
    Cursor cursor;
    cursor = database.rawQuery(" SELECT CustAccountId AS _id,AccountNo as AccountNo,BankName as BankName,BranchName as BranchName FROM tblCustAccount  WHERE CustRef =" + custRef , null);

    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    return cursor;
}

public ArrayList<String> getCustAccountString(long custRef) {
    Cursor cursor = getCustAccount(custRef);

    ArrayList<String> listAccount = new ArrayList<String>();

    do {
        listAccount.add(String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(1)));

    } while(cursor.moveToNext());

    return listAccount;
}
```

Comment: if `cursor` equals with `null` then your app must be get that `Exception`

Comment: FYI: Putting the title of your question in a search engine would have resulted with many posts with a correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

There's no data in the cursor. You should check that `moveToFirst()` succeeds before any of the `get...()` calls:

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
  do {
    listAccount.add(String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(1)));
  } while(cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

Comment: `if(cursor.moveToFirst) return cursor else return null` if you return null then it will coz other problems. So the real problem is the query din't succeed and the cursor does not point to the first row!.

Comment: @Raghunandan Yeah didn't suggest returning a null, added an example to clarify.

Comment: yes i understand i posted a comment to get it clarified. i was just curious about the else part

Comment: @Sanaz Either the code wasn't updated or this is not the code causing the exception. Consider adding full stacktrace in the question.

Answer (score 0):

use:-

```
if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
    return cursor;
    }
    return null;

public abstract boolean moveToFirst ()
```

Move the cursor to the first row.

This method will return false if the cursor is empty.

Returns
whether the move succeeded.

Comment: Returning a `null` will cause other problems such as NPE later in OP's code.

Comment: @laalto you can check null it is then return simple ArrayList object with no entry.

Comment: what problem? can you explain please.

Comment: 01-22 16:19:00.073: E/AndroidRuntime(27938): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-22 16:19:00.073: E/AndroidRuntime(27938): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
01-22 16:19:00.073: E/AndroidRuntime(27938):  at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:419)

Comment: you need to check before use check for moveToFrist if it return true then go further other wise simply return Empty String ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

try following code:

```
if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
     do {
        listAccount.add(String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(1)));

    } while(cursor.moveToNext());
 }
```